# structure of function using func arrays

Tags: c

please....

I am trying to make library which is intended like a lib based on struct
I wanna reach something like "mats.basic.add(1,1);"

first error when build is first line inside struct (both of them) and then
are, although editors hints me after dot operation like add or sub
next errors are "uknown members add, sub

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t (*p_fn1)(uint8_t,uint8_t);

uint8_t fn_add(uint8_t num1,uint8_t num2){
    return num1+num2;
}

uint8_t fn_sub(uint8_t num1,uint8_t num2){
    return num1-num2;
}

typedef struct mats {
    p_fn1 add=fn_add;
    p_fn1 sub=fn_sub;
}mats;

void init_mats(mats* t_mats){
    t_mats->add=fn_add;
    t_mats->sub=fn_sub;
}
int main()
{
    mats mats_s;
    init_mats(&mats_s);
    uint8_t c=mats_s.add(1,1);
    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;
}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: `p_fn1 add=fn_add;
    p_fn1 sub=fn_sub;` is invalid. It can not be assigned in the structure definition. Try `typedef struct mats {
    p_fn1 add;
    p_fn1 sub;
}mats;`. Also `fn_sum` typo as `fn_sub`

Comment: thanks you were right, so I cant assign adress of func in struct, it works now :)

Comment: changing `&d` to `%d` will improve the results, once you fix the struct definition

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to initialize struct members when you define the struct.  That's invalid syntax.

Remove those initializers from the definition.

```
typedef struct mats {
    p_fn1 add;
    p_fn1 sub;
}mats;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have methods that can be called on your types, write your program in C++. It has that feature; C does not.

There isn't any way to do this in pure C that won't be clumsy to write, slow to run, and/or use inappropriate amounts of memory. The specific way that you're trying doesn't work at all because you're trying to set fields on a *type*, rather than on an *instance* of that type, but even if you fixed that, you'd still run into some other fundamental limitations of the language.

Comment: So please...it's so bad to do it way I showed upper ?

All I wanna do is have a driver for display which will hints you

Like 

LCD_driver.write_data.alphanumeric.sentence("HELLO WORLD");

so as you can see i need at least three structures and pointers...

Is it so bad for MCU's ? (I intend to use it in 8bit,32bit...)

Comment: @VladimírŠustek That's actually particularly bad for a microcontroller. Calling through a function pointer is a relatively expensive operation, and compilers typically can't optimize it away. Again: If you want this sort of syntax, use C++.

Comment: So, C++ syntax is for those purposes,it ensures optimatization, and MCU will work well then ?

Thank you for advice !